# What port does Courier for Umbraco use?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco5, umbraco-contour

I have had a few problems setting up Courier for umbraco (v7).

After a bit of trial an error I have discovered the destination server has all its ports blocked other than 80.

Does anyone know what port I need to open up to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Courier just runs over port 80, as it's all web based.